# Windows Update Agent Update Failed

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update

I'm trying to install the latest version of Windows Update Agent, v7.2.6001.788, and the installation failed with error code of 0x800b0100. Running Windows Server 2008 SP1.

The relevant WindowsUpdate.log section:

```
2009-08-03  16:17:49:334    3544    d28 Misc    ===========  Logging initialized (build: 7.2.6001.788, tz: +0100)  ===========
2009-08-03  16:17:49:334    3544    d28 Misc      = Process: d:\fcc0f96e893296900e6501a601\wusetup.exe
2009-08-03  16:17:49:332    3544    d28 Setup   Windows Update Client standalone setup : resource dll path is d:\fcc0f96e893296900e6501a601\en\wusetup.exe.mui
2009-08-03  16:17:49:335    3544    d28 Setup   Evaluating CBS package "d:\fcc0f96e893296900e6501a601\WUClient-SelfUpdate-Core-TopLevel.cab"
2009-08-03  16:17:49:556    3544    d28 Setup   Package will be installed
2009-08-03  16:17:49:556    3544    d28 Setup   Evaluating CBS package "d:\fcc0f96e893296900e6501a601\WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX.cab"
2009-08-03  16:17:49:580    3544    d28 Setup   Package will be installed
2009-08-03  16:17:49:580    3544    d28 Setup   Evaluating CBS package "d:\fcc0f96e893296900e6501a601\WUClient-SelfUpdate-Aux-TopLevel.cab"
2009-08-03  16:17:49:665    3544    d28 Setup   Package will be installed
2009-08-03  16:17:49:709    3544    d28 Setup   Windows Update Client standalone setup : eula file path is d:\fcc0f96e893296900e6501a601\en\eula.rtf
2009-08-03  16:17:52:337    3544    de0 Misc    WARNING: LoadLibrary failed for srclient.dll with hr:8007007E
2009-08-03  16:17:52:338    3544    de0 Setup   Installing CBS package "d:\fcc0f96e893296900e6501a601\WUClient-SelfUpdate-Core-TopLevel.cab"
2009-08-03  16:17:53:895    3544    de0 Setup   WARNING: CBS operation failed, error = 0x800B0100
2009-08-03  16:17:53:898    3544    de0 Setup   WARNING: Install of setup package "d:\fcc0f96e893296900e6501a601\WUClient-SelfUpdate-Core-TopLevel.cab" failed, error = 0x800B0100
2009-08-03  16:18:04:976    3544    d28 Setup   wusetup has finished.  Exit code is 0. Reboot is NOT needed
```

I think something went wrong twhen loading the srclient.dll.

Things that I have done and still no fix:

- `msiexec /unregister` and `msiexec /register`
- `regsvr32 wuapi.dll`
- Run CheckSUR tool and restart

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this from the command prompt?

```
net stop cryptsvc
rename %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2old
net start cryptsvc
```

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956702

Method for Windows 7, Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008
To resolve this issue, run the System Update Readiness Tool (Checksur.exe). To do this, follow these steps: 
Download and run the System Update Readiness Tool. This tool runs a one-time scan for inconsistencies that may prevent future servicing operations.
For more information about how to download and run the Checksur.exe tool, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
947821 Description of the System Update Readiness Tool for Windows Vista
Try to install updates again.
Note After you run the tool, the Checksur.log file is located in the following location: %systemroot%\Logs\CBS\

In a default installation of Windows 7 and Windows Vista, this file is in the following folder:

C:\Windows\Logs\CBS

Comment: Have you seen the list of things that I've done? How is this different than the third item?

Answer (score 0):

check that you're running the latest revision of the checksur tool. microsoft releases updates occasionally so one you downloaded last year may not fix your problem.

as of right now, the latest one is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821